# Excel syntax for getting the value in another table based on 2 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know what is the best syntax if i want to get the price of an item depending on the specific product and its unit of measure because a product can be sold per bag or per kilo. Here's a sample content of excel sheet. The only required input for the user is the enter product name and unit of measure in the Orders Sheet.

Orders Sheet

```
Item Purchased     | Unit     | Price
-------------------+----------+---------
Product 1          | Bag      | 1000
Product 1          | Kilo     | 100
```

~~~~~~~

Price List Sheet

```
Item      | Unit of Measure     | Price
----------+---------------------+--------
Product 1 | Bag                 | 1000
Product 1 | Kilo                | 100
Product 2 | Bag                 | 2000
```

Comment: Looks like matching on two columns. Give this a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097499/pull-a-third-value-on-the-basis-of-two-criterias-using-index-and-match-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS`, which can be used specifically when the result you want is a numeric value:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, E2, B:B, F2)
```

[image]

That's assuming though that your price list is a true price list, meaning no item is duplicated (e.g. Product 1, Bag doesn't appear more than once).